# Deduction in Prolog

Tags: prolog

This is an elementary Prolog question. I'm trying to implement reasoning that may be informally expressed like this:

The (necessary but not sufficient) conditions for x(X) to be true are that a(X) and b(X) must hold. We know that x(mary). Those conditions must have held for x(mary) to be the case. It *is* the case. Therefore a(mary) and b(mary) are both true.

The following code clearly *doesn't* do what I have in mind:

```
a(jim).
b(jack).
x(X) :- a(X), b(X).
x(mary).
```

If I now ask a(mary), Prolog answers with a No.

I'm pretty sure I understand why it answers this way. I just don't know how to correctly implement what I want.

UPDATE:

The above example is simplified. In the actual problem I'm working on, a and b are intertwined. Instead of `x(X) :- a(X), b(X).`, I actually have `r(A,B,C) :- p(A,D), p(C,E), a(D,n), a(E,c), s(B,E,F,2), s(C,E,D,1), s(C,E,F,1).`. That is, for `r(A,B,C)` to hold, it is necessary that all the interlinked conditions on the right hold *together*. Now it doesn't seem right to replace this with a series of rules `p(A,D) :- r(A,B,C). a(D,n) :- r(A,B,C).` and so on, because, as I understand it, the `D` in the `p(A,D)` is no longer the same as the `D` in the `a(D,n)`, these being now totally independent rules. I could easily implement the reasoning I want in a (deductive) automated theorem prover for first order logic, which I am more familiar with than with Prolog.

Another example. Consider this Prolog code:

```
breathable(X) :- part(X,Y), atom(Y,o).
part(air,oxygen).
breathable(air).
```

Air is breathable. Air contains oxygen. I want to infer that `atom(oxygen,o)`. But Prolog will answer No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `breathable` example, you'd need an added rule:

```
atom(X, Y) :- breathable(Y), part(Y, X).
```

Without this rule, it's logic would not be implicitly and consistently true with your existing rule base and fact schema. It is, in part, a converse of your existing rule. From a purely logical perspective, the converse of an implication doesn't necessarily hold true just because the original implication is true. The truth of `atom(oxygen, o)` in the simple example given is established by the converse of the existing rule *plus* currently available, specific facts. This is basically a form of *abductive* logic, not *deduction* as your question title suggests. Without the new `atom/2` rule, if new `part` facts are added later without even changing your fact schema, that abductive process may cause the example query to fail or be non-provable, different than the current result. So it's not reliable without an explicit rule.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful, thank you. What confuses me is that I can obtain the desired result (for example, by hand) using pure deduction (no abduction involved). From the sentences 1. forall X Y: breathable(X) -> (part(X,Y) and atom(Y,o)) 2. part(air,oxygen) 3. breathable(air), it follows purely deductively in first-order logic that 4. atom(oxygen,o). I suspect this is related to your last two sentences, which I don't fully understand. Could you provide an example please?

Comment: @VelvetGhost because you're mixing facts and rules, you can "deduce" but only if you assume your currently available facts is your complete set of facts. I (poorly) tried to explain in my answer that the deduction can change if the facts are augmented. If you look at it strictly from a rule perspective, you cannot deduce the result you want without the additional rule.

Comment: Thanks. Accepted this answer. I used Prolog code implementing an abductive logic programming system to obtain what I wanted.

Comment: @VelvetGhost I hope my answer was helpful. You're allowed to post your solution as an answer and accept your own answer if you wish as well!

Answer (score 1):

You probably think of it the wrong way. Currently you have written: "*`x(X)` holds given `a(X)` and `b(X)` hold, or `X` is `mary`.*".

Not the opposite way. If you want to write: "*`a(A)` holds given `A` is `jim` or `X(A)`.*", you should write:

```
a(jim).
a(A) :-
    x(A).
```

So you probably want to write:

```
a(jim).
a(A) :-
    x(A).

b(jack).
b(B) :-
    x(B).

x(mary).
```

Comment: This works for the simplified example I gave, but doesn't in general do what I want. Please see the updated question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

"Those conditions must have held for x(mary) to be the case. It is the case. Therefore a(mary) and b(mary) are both true."

Let's express that in code, shall we?

```
a(X) :- x(X).
b(X) :- x(X).
```

That should produce the expected result.

Comment: This works for the simplified example I gave, but doesn't in general do what I want. Please see the updated question. Thanks.